# Is there a way I can show a short movie intro clip when my iphone app starts?

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

Is there a way I can show a short movie intro clip when my iphone app starts? There are many apps that have movie intro clip in app store.

Comment: Each time it starts? That would be damn annoying...

I already dislike apps that don't follow the guidelines for Default.png, showing a logo instead :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as an iPhone user, *please do not do this*. Put a 'video demo' menu option instead.

When I want to use your app, I want to use it *right now*, not after some video plays.